# Is this equivalent to overflow check

Tags: disassembly

IDA generates the following disassembly from a software :

```
.text:004D594E add     eax, ebx
.text:004D5950 mov     [esi], eax
.text:004D5952 cmp     ebx, eax
.text:004D5954 jbe     short loc_
```

So we add `ebx` to `eax`, then we check if `ebx` is lower or equal to `eax`.

This is either a check to see if ebx is negative or to see if the addition resulted in a value higher than `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Any hint on how I should interpret this?

Answer (score 2):

> we check if `eax` is lower or equal to `ebx`.

No, `cmp ebx, eax; jbe ...` checks to see if `ebx` `<=` `eax`, not the other way around.

Comment: ugg, edited the question

Comment: The question here is really how can adding ebx to eax make eax lower than ebx

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: So this is an overflow check, is there any other way to interpret those operations?

Comment: The question here is really how can adding ebx to eax make eax lower than ebx  only when eax wraps around and becomes zero that is when eax = 0xffffffff and ebx = 1 adding ebx t o eax turns eax to 0 which is then below ebx assemble this inplace and execute and you can observe esi = 0xffffffff when ebfe is reached MOV     EAX, 0 MOV     EBX, 1MOV  ESI, EAX ADD     EAX, EBX CMP     EBX, EAX JBE     SHORT 063FB2
JMP     SHORT 1063FB0
JMP     SHORT 01063FA8